# Complexity classes that are low for equivalent definitions of $\mathrm{PP}$

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

**What is the biggest complexity class that is low for each other equivalent definition of $\mathrm{PP}$?**

I already know that $\mathrm{PP}^\mathrm{BQP}=\mathrm{PP}$. This is a lowness result using standard definition of $\mathrm{PP}$.

Since, it is known that $\mathrm{PP} = \mathrm{PostBQP} = \mathrm{PQP}$.

1. If we use $\mathrm{PostBQP}$, then what is the biggest complexity class that is low for this equivalent definition.
2. Similarly, if we use $\mathrm{PQP}$, then what is the biggest complexity class that is low for this equivalent definition.

For known results: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity)

Answer (score 0):

$\mathrm{BQP}$ is semmingly the largest class that is low for $\mathrm{PP}$.

Using the definition of $\mathrm{PostBQP}$ (a $\mathrm{BQP}$ circuit with postselection) and $\mathrm{BQP}^\mathrm{BQP}=\mathrm{BQP}$ we can also derive that $\mathrm{PostBQP}^\mathrm{BQP}=\mathrm{PostBQP}$

In comparison to $\mathrm{MidBitP}$ (denote $\mathrm{MP}$) for short, all these classes are low for $\mathrm{MP}$: $\mathrm{ModPH}$, $\mathrm{BPP}^{\oplus \mathrm{P}}$. The last one ($\mathrm{BPP}^{\oplus \mathrm{P}}$) already contains $\mathrm{PH}$. That is the power of the middle bit. More on middle bit, see [here](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/sct/1992/2955/00/00215386.pdf).